# How can one clear the date on AngularStrap's (Bootstrap) bs-datepicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Referring to this directive for AngularJS, which wraps Bootstrap's datepicker: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker

I'm unable to find a way to clear the control programmatically once it's been set. I have tried setting it to null and empty string, neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to controller:

```
$scope.clickMe = function(){  
   $scope.datepicker = null;
 };
```

It will clear date input.

see [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGql0D)

Comment: I've copied your exact example into my project and this flat out doesn't work. Could it be that I'm using an older version of one of the dependencies (AngularJS, AngularStrap, Boostrap)?

Comment: See Plunker index.html header :)

Comment: Just looked at again, the header vs. mine is different, and while neither show version, I changed mine to your links and it now works. Sheesh, now I gotta regression test to make sure other stuff I was doing still works. Thanks though, huge help.